# jquery tools - overlay positioning problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here is the link:
http://pangeaadvisors.org/projects.asp

2009 Projects position in the center as I want them to be. But click on 2007 projects. When clicked, overlay positioned on the right side and without the background.

Comment: What browser do you see issues in?

Comment: Firefox 3.5, IE 8 beta and IE 7.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because your div elements for each overlay appear within the < ul > tags. Right now you have (i think its invalid HTML to have it like this)

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a></a>
    </li>
    <div overlay />
</ul>
```

Have you tried it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a></a>
        <div overlay />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes. Didn't make any difference.